# i cant make AnimatedModal.js close and fade work

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/objecttest/directory/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>

<body>
  <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">DEMO01</a>

  <div id="animatedModal">
  <div class="close-animatedModal"><span class="fa fa-close"></span></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="thum">

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

<script src="/objecttest/directory/js/animatedModal.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  //demo 01
  $("#demo01").animatedModal({
    animatedIn: 'zoomIn',
    animatedOut: 'bounceOut',
    color: '#39BEB9',
    beforeOpen: function() {
      var children = $(".thumb");
      var index = 0;
      function addClassNextChild() {
        if (index == children.length) return;
        children.eq(index++).show().velocity("transition.expandIn", {
          opacity: 1,
          stagger: 250
        });
        window.setTimeout(addClassNextChild, 200);
      }
      addClassNextChild();
    },
    afterClose: function() {
      $(".thumb").hide();
    }
  })

});
</script>

</html>
```

i cant make the AnimatedModal.js work on my website, somehow it seem wrong according to the website , seem like it wont fade and i cant close the popup, i followed the web build. can anyone point out my problem ?

here is the [website](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/) i followed

Comment: Check if you have any console errors in browser..

Comment: none i checked.

Answer (score 1):

You have not included relevant `CSS` necessary for this plugin to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/objecttest/directory/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.0/animate.min.css"/>

<!--Add the above CSS link reference-->
```

That should help you work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` of the close-button has to match the modals `class`.

> THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID  class="close-animatedModal"

So if your modals `id` is for example `modal1` your close-button should have the class `close-modal1`

Answer (score 0):

Try including `animatedModal.js` inside the `</body>` tag.

Also don't forget to include the css file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.0/animate.min.css">`
 inside `<head>` tag

Lastly, throw a `debugger;` inside your script. If execution in chrome doesn't pause, you know something isn't working correctly.